# Connection string is not valid or Error Locating Server/Instance

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I reinstaled my PC and now I have problems with my SQL connection string or with SQL Server 2012 Enterprise 
Error I get:

```
"... (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)"  or 

"... (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"
```

In SQL Server Management Studio server instance looks like this:

```
TOM-PC (SQL Server 11.0.3128 - Tom-PC\Tom)
```

And My SQL connection string in ASP.NET XML config. file:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.\TOM-PC;Database=D:\Programming\InvoiceManager\invocemanagerSQL.mdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Tried everything, in firewall added port 1434 or 1433 tested both, not working, `"SQL Server Browser"` Service is running, TCP/IP Enabled, Allow remote connections to this server, even tried 4 different connection strings, nothing worked.
Before it worked like a charm, not fully but worked. Why not fully? Because I couldn't work on my local machine with both studios `"VS2010"` and `"SQL Management studio"` at the same time, if I needed change something in database manually, I needed to stop or restart SQL Server process and service, then I get in database, and read tables. Now, nothing is working!
What I do or did wrong? Where seems to be the problem? Why always are problems with SQL servers and it's connectionstrings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing in Management Studio is as follows:

```
Instance Name (SQL Server version - Domain\LoggedInUser)
```

You are logged in using integrated authentication (i.e. your windows logon account) but not specifying it in the connection string. This will try to use the currently logged on user for the ASP.Net application, which will almost certainly not be running as your windows account. It will either be one of the local or network service accounts or a built-in ASP.Net user.

You're also using the wrong variable name to attach the database file, if this is actually what you want rather than connecting to an actual database on the server.

What I suggest you do is enable SQL Server authentication on your instance, create a new user and give it permissions to the database as required.

You would then log in using the following format:

```
Server=myServerAddress; Database=myDataBase; User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;
```

Where `myServerAddress` would be `localhost` or `TOM-PC`; `Database` would be the name of the database as it appears in Management Studio; `User Id` would be the username for the user you just created and `Password` would be the password you set for them during creation.

If you do actually want to attach a database file then your connection string changes to use this format:

```
Server=myServerAddress; AttachDbFilename=C:\Path\To\Database\File.mdf; Database=myDataBase; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Typically, you can get most connection string variants that you will need from: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: I'm so dumb, it worked with new user! Thanks!
But without creating new user, why I can't connect?

Comment: Like I said, the IIS worker process (w3wp) runs under a different account to your domain user account. It usually runs as the network service account under default settings and that account won't have permissions in SQL Server. You could look up the application pool's identity (the service account) and give that permissions in SQL Server but that's not considered a good practise and either dedicated windows accounts or SQL Server accounts should be used.