# Cannot connect UWP app. to SQL Server 2017 instance:

Tags: sql-server, uwp, sql-server-2017

UWP app. returns

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>   The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)"

Trying to connect to a SQL Server 2017 instance.

This is all on a local dev. machine, Windows 10 (no remote).

Have followed advice in SO to no avail: [Connection string is not valid or Error Locating Server/Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830289/connection-string-is-not-valid-or-error-locating-server-instance)

- SQL server service is running.
- Can connect in SSMS.
- "SQL Server Browser" Service is running, TCP/IP Enabled.
- I stopped Kaspersky & then Windows firewall altogether. No joy.

Connection string that fails:

```
@"Data Source=JUPITER\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=GumbysNorthwind;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxx_xxxx";
```

Same UWP App does manage to connect to SQL server 2014 instance.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

I followed the [Use a SQL Server database in a UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases) document to do tests. I can connect to the sqlserver database successfully.

[image]

Please check the **[First, setup your solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases#first-set-up-your-solution)** section, if you have set the correct target/min version, capability etc.

My connection string is different from you. E.g, 'Data Source=172.xx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;;User ID=sa;Password=Password'

I have not stopped the Windows firewall, but I add a new rule in 'Inbound Rules'. I add the TCP port 1433 in the rule and allow the connection.

Comment: Thank you Xavier for your accurate answer. Yes you're on the money. I too had changed the connection string to "Data Source=127.0.0.1,51746;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=SSPI" + allowed the port through the firewall, and it worked fine.

Comment: @WillyGumby If my answer helps you solve your issue, please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with UWP. With application running with Visual studio, it was working fine. But after making it as package and installing it on same machine it was not working for me. 
For me it started working when I put the localhost IP:"127.0.0.1\sqlexpress" instead of computername\sqlexpress for data source. Hope this is helpful.

Thanks,
Shashi Bhan

Answer (score 0):

UWP disabled connection to local database for some stupid reason. Nothing worked for me. I finally got it working by running the following command in command prompt (as admin) in C: drive

```
checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n=YourAppPackageName
```